# How to convert scanned document to text-based doc/pdf?

Tags: macos, pdf, print-to-pdf, file-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple, free OCR software (for OS X)?](https://superuser.com/questions/9916/simple-free-ocr-software-for-os-x)

I have a 58-page document that is image-based scans of text.

I need this document in text format.

Is there an easy way to do this on OS X (10.6)?

Commercial software recommendations are acceptable :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the grandaddy of commercial software that can be used for this would be [Adobe Acrobat Pro](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro.html).